# Make node take up horizontal space equivalent of two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{minsizebox} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10!green!20, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, inner sep=0.5em, text centered, rounded corners=4, align=center]
\tikzstyle{purpleminbox} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!15, inner sep=0.5em, text centered, minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=center, drop shadow, align=center]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node[minsizebox] (tl) {Top Left};
    \node[minsizebox, right of=tl, xshift=2cm] (tr) {Top Right};
    \node[purpleminbox, below of=tl] (ml) {Middle left};
    \node[purpleminbox, below of=tr] (mr) {Middle Right};
    \node[minsizebox, below of=ml] (bl) {Bottom Left};
    \node[minsizebox, below of=mr] (br) {Bottom Right};
    \draw[arrow] (tl) -- (ml);
    \draw[arrow] (tr) -- (mr);
    \draw[arrow] (ml) -- (bl);
    \draw[arrow] (mr) -- (br);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## **Currently**:

[image: ![enter image description here]

## **Desired**:

[image]

Basically, I want the middle node to take up the space of two nodes.
The arrows should still point from where they did previously, i.e. the respective nodes' "north" and "south" positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: nodes and arrows]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{minsizebox} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10!green!20, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, inner sep=0.5em, text centered, rounded corners=4, align=center]
\tikzstyle{purpleminbox} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!15, inner sep=0.5em, text centered, minimum width=7.5cm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=center, drop shadow, align=center]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \node[minsizebox] (tl) {Top Left};
    \node[minsizebox, right of=tl, xshift=2cm] (tr) {Top Right};

    \path (tl) -- (tr) node[midway](t){};
    \node[purpleminbox, below of=t] (m) {Middle};

    \node[minsizebox, below = 3cm of tl] (bl) {Bottom Left};
    \node[minsizebox, below = 3cm of tr] (br) {Bottom Right};
    \draw[arrow] (tl) -- (tl|-m.north);
    \draw[arrow] (tr) -- (tr|-m.north);
    \draw[arrow] (bl|-m.south) -- (bl);
    \draw[arrow] (br|-m.south) -- (br);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        minsizebox/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10!green!20, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=1cm, inner sep=0.5em, text centered, rounded corners=4, align=center},
        purpleminbox/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!15, inner sep=0.5em, text centered, minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=1cm, anchor=center, align=center},
        arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
        node distance=2cm]
    \node[minsizebox] (tl) {Top Left};
    \node[minsizebox, right of=tl, xshift=2cm] (tr) {Top Right};
    \node[purpleminbox, below of=tl] (ml) {Middle left};
    \node[purpleminbox, below of=tr] (mr) {Middle Right};
    \node[minsizebox, below of=ml] (bl) {Bottom Left};
    \node[minsizebox, below of=mr] (br) {Bottom Right};
    \node[fit=(ml) (mr), purpleminbox, drop shadow, inner sep=0pt, label=center:Middle] (m) {};
    \draw[arrow] (tl) -- (ml);
    \draw[arrow] (tr) -- (mr);
    \draw[arrow] (ml) -- (bl);
    \draw[arrow] (mr) -- (br);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]